# html->link doesn't put link properly according to router with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have this router:

```
Router::connect
(
  ':renting/:model_name/:number_name/',
  array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'view'),
  array(
    'pass' => array('renting', 'model_name', 'number_name'),
    'renting' => 'renting'
  )
);
```

When I do this in a view

```
$html->link("NAME",
  array(
    'controller' => 'cars',
    'action' => 'view',
    'renting',
    $model_name,
    $number_name
  )
);
```

I obtain this link on the page: `mypage.com/cars/view/renting/mustang/03212xd`

and i need obtain `mypage.com/renting/mustang/03212xd`

Im stuck here. Thank you. Note: `muypage.com/renting/mustang/03212xd` redirects right to my controller function but not when use `$html->link` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name your parameters, you need to name your parameters:

```
array(
    'controller'  => 'cars',
    'action'      => 'view',
    'renting'     => 'renting',
    'model_name'  => $model_name,
    'number_name' => $number_name
)
```

If `:renting` is always `'renting'`, you don't need to parameterize it:

```
Router::connect('/renting/:model_name/:number_name/',
                array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'view', 'renting'),
                array('pass' => array('model_name', 'number_name')));

$html->link(…, array(
    'controller'  => 'cars',
    'action'      => 'view',
    'renting',
    'model_name'  => $model_name,
    'number_name' => $number_name
));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didnt see any example as this in documentation.